# rails devise app - supporting user account/profile settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have developed a basic rails 3.2 app using devise (2.2.3) for authentication. Now I need to add support for the user account/profile settings. The additional attributes (of profile/account) that can be updated by the end user are part of the User model.

I need suggestion on how this can be supported? Which action of the UsersController would meet the requirement? I added an edit action in the UsersController for the same. When I run 'rake routes', I get the following

```
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
```

cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
               **edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show**
                    root        /                              home#index

When the edit form is submitted, the form sends a message to "/users/1/edit" with PUT and I get the routing error that
No route matches [PUT] "/users/1/edit"

Is this the right way to modify the user settings? Should the form be posted with "PUT"? If so, how do I make a route entry with PUT instead of GET as above?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users to be able to update "their" `User` object then you will need to setup a routing entry for them in your `routes.rb`. Something like:

```
resource :users => [:edit, :update]
```

Your form should be PUTing to `/users/:id` not `/users/:id/edit`.

Once this is setup you will be able to use form helpers to create forms for users to edit `User` objects. You will want to consider security here and make sure they don't update fields they should not have access to.

Rails doing a PUT request is correct as one of the main tenants of rails is to try to make everything RESTful.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I am able update the settings. When you mention about security related to forms, you are basically suggesting to properly make use of attr_accessible only for the values that can be set? or are you referring to something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
```

This is fine because going to users/:id/edit is simply **getting** the form. The form is then filled out and the act of pressing "submit" will make a **PUT** request to /users/:id. You're just missing this second part.

Jeremy's answer should fix the routes problem.